# obtaining $y'$ from $r = 1 + \sin\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

Just want to check if this is the idea for this

$$x = r\cos\theta$$ 
$$y = r\sin\theta$$

so now we substitute

$$x = (1 + \sin\theta)\cos\theta$$ 
$$y = (1 + \sin\theta)\sin\theta$$

get the derivative of $x$ and $y$ in that form (after distributing) and make it $dy/dx$, thus

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta \cos\theta}{-\sin\theta+\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}$$

Dont know where to go from there. if there is any simplification or another step I'm not aware of. But is this the concept?

edit:
Also as a follow up the $y''=d^2y/dx^2$ means we get the double prime of the top and bottom or just the top with the $dx$ being squared on the bottom?

Comment: Well... evaluate $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$. Then, by Chain Rule, $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d\theta}\cdot (\frac{dx}{d\theta})^{-1} = \frac{dy}{d\theta}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$. As for the denominator, you should have $-2sin^2(x) - sin(x) + 1 = -(2sin(x)-1)(sin(x)+1)$. So you can't simplify.